# Should I put cert at both App Gw and Web App level

Tags: azure-application-gateway

I have uploaded cert on azure application gateway but does not have done SSL binding at web app. Do I need to do SSL binding at web app level even I have uploaded cert on App GW?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are deploying Azure Web App behind Application gateway, in end to end scenarios you don't need to add auth cert. You can just enable App Service check box.

The reason being if the cert in Web App changes without notice, it will bring down the site. So, you don't need to add the cert to Application Gateway HTTP settings.

Comment: You meant 'enable App service check box' in http settings? If yes then I have already done this. On http settings i can see this message '
Authentication certificates are not required for trusted Azure certificates for end to end ssl to work'

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I meant. You don't need auth cert for Web Apps in the backend for end to end SSL.